# Building solution using Git-based Visual Studio Online fails with project references

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

I've got a Git-based Visual Studio Online instance configured and setup.

I've structured the Team Project to have one repository for every solution to divide things up. One repository for "CommonLibrary" and one for "WebApplication1".

I'm using Project References in Visual Studio to reference from WebApplication1 to CommonLibrary.

CommonLibrary has it's own solution but the project is added as an existing project to WebApplication1 and referenced in that way.

When building this locally, everything is fine.

However, when trying to build on Visual Studio Online, the build fails with the error message that the referenced project CommonLibrary couldn't be found.

I can't find any properties in the Build Definition for specifying the source to build from different repos.

[image]

Couldn't find any resources about "How to build a solution that references from projects in another repository with Git-based Visual Studio Online".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), then initialize your submodules as part of the build process.

Comment: I have tried this with no success. Can you provide any example from a Build Template that actually successfully can restore submodules?